# Преблемы при обрезание строки substr

Tags: php

Привет, есть умена переменная с текстом

```
$testtext = "Тут текст";
```

Когда я ее обрезаю получается вот такая бяка в конце  `�...`

Вот собственно Весь код

```
if (strlen($testtext)>100) 
{ 
echo  "".substr($testtext, 0, 100)."..."; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "$testtext"; 
}
```

Как обрезать строку без крякозябы в конце, работаю на локальном сервере.

PS: Ребята предлагали `mb_substr` но уменя на локалке неработает эта функция.

Comment: использовать тот самый mb_substr, отделять частицу "не" пробелами от глаголов. простой substr работает с байтами и режет многобайтовые кодировки где придется.

Comment: @Etki об mb_substr я уже в курсе, дело в том что на локальном сервере он у меня работать нехочет, как раз зараз ищу информацию как это исправить. А можно эту крякозябу просто вирезать с строки - Только что идея пришла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна функция для работы с многобайтовыми строками [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php). Полная инфа есть в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mbstring.php), в том числе и [установка](http://php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.installation.php).

Вот ваш пример + рефакторинг:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); // можно 1 раз в коде указать кодировку

$testtext = "Тут очень длинный текст, который длиннее чем 100 символов и поэтому он будет обрезан, что бы поместился например в заголовке";
if (mb_strlen($testtext) > 100) 
{ 
    $testtext = mb_substr($testtext, 0, 100) . "..."; 
} 
echo $testtext;
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь.

Comment: установил mb_substr() но всеравно видает ошыбку  Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_substr()

Comment: @Анатолий ОС? Версия php?

Comment: @Анатолий думаю вам поможет вот этот вариант – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035698/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-substr

Comment: РАЗОБРАЛСЯ Скачал файл php_mbstring.dll у положил егов (тут диск сервера):\usr\local\php5\ext Посли этого открил файл php.ini нашел в нем строку ;extension=php_mbstring.dll и убрал с начала двоеточие, сохранил и посли этого перезапустил сервер. Все стало работать, всем спасибо за помощь.